# When using a formula to set a cell to the value of another cell, how can I keep notes that are on the original cell?

Tags: google-sheets

**The Question:**
I hope the title above makes sense. Basically, I have a formula to generate random items from a table filled with all the possible items of interest. I go through each cell in the table, and if certain conditions are met the item appears in the random generated item table. This is all working great so far, the only trouble is that the original items have notes attached to them to describe them, but these notes don't carry over to the new table. Is there any way to keep the notes on the new generated cells?

**Level of Understanding and What I've Researched so Far:**
As a bit of further information, I am not very familiar with google sheets, although I have a decent amount of programming experience (I understand things from variables to functions in general programming, and I understand how to use variables, operations, nested IF's, and switch functions in google sheets). I have tried to google this issue and I haven't found any easy fixes, and it looks like I may have to use something called Apps Script. I am willing to try learning it if I need too, but I have never used it before and it's unclear to me if it will help solve my current problem. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: AFAIK you can't access notes via a formula as they are metadata, however if it were possible to store the information currently in the notes instead in an adjacent column of the source table, I'm pretty certain you'd be able to use a formula to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Please take the [Tour] and review [ask]. If you'd like help with a formula please include it.  If you want help with a custom function please include your script and any errors you are encountering.  Apps Script is JS so your programming background will come in handy. Look into `range.getNote()` / `range.getNotes()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's in bad taste to answer your own question on here, but I found a solution and thought I'd share it, and hopefully it helps out a few people.

So, after looking a bit more, I think it may be impossible to keep notes from one cell into a newly generated cell without using Apps Scripts or something similar (if anyone knows if this is incorrect or not please reply as I would really like to know myself). So, Apps Scripts seems to be needed.

To use Apps Script, go to **Extensions > Apps Scripts**. If you get an error, trying opening Apps Scripts in incognito mode.

In Apps scripts, the following code (with your information entered) can help transfer notes from one column to another:

```
function getSheetNotes() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // gets active spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("insertSheetname"); // Example: ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var range = sheet.getRange("insertSheetname!columnCellStart:columnCellEnd"); // Example: sheet.getRange("Sheet1!A1:A50");
  var notes = range.getNotes();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < notes.length;i++){
    
    var cell = range.getCell(i+1,1);
    var newcell = cell.offset(rowOffset,columnOffset); // example: cell.offset(0,10);
    
    // Clear any current notes in new cell
    newcell.clearNote();
    
    // if original cell has notes, add notes
    if(notes[i]){
      var note = notes[i];      
      newcell.setNote(note);   
    }
  }

}
```

The key part in this is the `.getNotes()` and `.setNote()` methods, as they work to get notes from a range and then set a note in a cell.